# What are gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE and gl.MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE exacly?

Tags: webgl

I would like to display a graphic (map) in a canvas.
Now this error message appears for large displays:

```
WebGL warning: width/height: Requested size 8316x3141 was too large, but resize to 4158x1570 succeeded.
```

I found this code snippet on the website https://docs.developer.canva.com/apps/frontend-development/webgl.

```
// Ensure we can render images this size
  const maxTextureSize = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE);
  const maxRenderBufferSize = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE);
  const maxSize = Math.max(state.image.width, state.image.height);
  if (maxSize > maxTextureSize || maxSize > maxRenderBufferSize) {
    throw new Error("Failed to render image. The image is too large.");
  }
```

But neither https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices nor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getParameter explain to me exactly what the parameters `gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and `MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE` mean. I can't find any other documentation.

For me, the error already occurs when my image is much smaller.

Example
maxTextureSize = 16384
maxRenderBufferSize = 16384
mymaxSize = 8316

shows the warnung

```
 WebGL warning: width/height: Requested size 8316x3141 was too large, but resize to 4158x1570 succeeded.
```

and does not render properly.

Answer (score 0):

> For 1D and 2D textures (and any texture types that use similar dimensionality, like cubemaps) the max size of either dimension is GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE

[Khronos OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture#:%7E:text=For%201D%20and%202D%20textures,of%20either%20dimension%20is%20GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.)

The same applies for `MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE` except that it pertains to renderbuffers created via `createRenderbuffer` or implicitly by the canvas as a backbuffer.

There's been some GPU drivers that falsely report sizes that they're not able to support, are you by chance using some age-old integrated or mobile graphics solution?